# Meta Mask - burn transaction

Tags: blockchain, metamask, nft

I am new to MetaMask API. I am looking for how to burn a NFT, but I cannot find it in the documentation.

I've seen a post on Stackoverflow similar to what I am looking for, but the burn transaction was done with Solidity. Is there anyway that I can achieve this by using MetaMask API?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you so much.
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metamask's job is to connect you to the networks and provide you with account service. Burning an NFT is calling the burn method written on the contract.

NFT is eventually an ERC721 token, it is a smart contract and if burn functionality is not written, you cannot burn it or kill it.

Burning an NFT effectively destroys the token and removes it entirely from the Ethereum blockchain. On the NFT platform that you are using, there should be an option like "BURN THE TOKEN". Once you click on it, you calling the burn method on the smart contract.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification Yilmaz. I was under the impression that, since Metamask API could create a transaction, so it must be able to destroy one. I need to read more about Blockchain.

Comment: metamask is a wallet that connects you to the blockchain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736559/is-there-some-relation-between-window-ethereum-injected-by-metamask-and-web3-js/70737473#70737473

Comment: Thank you so much Yilmaz. This helps a lot. This is very much appreciated.

Comment: I did accept the answer, but unfortunately my reputation is not high enough ( need to be 15 to cast a vote), so Stackoverflow would not show here, but it said, it would put my "accept the answer" in the system

Comment: @w-dev you dont need reputation to accept. accepting is different from upvoting :)