# Is there some relation between window.ethereum injected by metamask and web3.js? Can we use both?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I'm learning to program DApps and a question that came up is the difference between the API injected by Metamask and web3.js. As I understand it, MetaMask injects an object that has its own API, which has nothing to do with the web3.js library. Is this correct? And can I still use the web3.js library with MetaMask? In the latter case, how would I do it? If anyone can explain further about this difference, I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Also please understand what other kind of wallet providers your Dapp can have: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-to-your-dapp-and-different-ethereum-wallet-types/82532#82532

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`web3` is an older implementation which still some clients might use,

`window.ethereum` is the new api. since some clients still use `web3` we should still check for it.

Metamask connects you to the blockchain. Blockchain consists of blocks of data and these blocks of data are stored on nodes. Without nodes, you cannot access blockchain data.

MetaMask allows connectivity to the Ethereum blockchain through the infrastructure available at Infura ( https://infura.io ). This allows users to interact with the blockchain without having to install any node locally. infura  connects to
to different nodes in a different environment, such as mainnet, rinkeby, ropsten, etc.

[image]

web3js or web3py libraries are not related to metamask web3. Metamask provides a provider to `web3.js` library. This provider tells `web3.js` library which network we are going to communicate with and then connects to a node in that network.

Once you get the provider, you instantiate a web3 instance:

```
   const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

then you create a contract instance

```
contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      Contract.abi,
      Contract.address
    );
```

Now with `contract.methods` you can call the methods on the contract. Also web3js library provides too many util functions like hashing, converting units etc

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Please correct me if I'm thinking wrong. Through the MetaMask provider it would be possible, in principle, to make any kind of transaction with the blockchain, but then you would have to write the JSON of the transaction yourself. Web3.js is a library that unwraps, so to speak, this need to write the JSON yourself.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMorais Metamask just connects you to network to interact. when with web3 you can apply methods. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it was of great help.